# How to compute the nth root of a very big integer

Tags: python, math, nth-root

I need a way to compute the nth root of a long integer in Python.

I tried `pow(m, 1.0/n)`, but it doesn't work:

> OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float

Any ideas?

By long integer I mean REALLY long integers like:

> 11968003966030964356885611480383408833172346450467339251
>   196093144141045683463085291115677488411620264826942334897996389
>   485046262847265769280883237649461122479734279424416861834396522
>   819159219215308460065265520143082728303864638821979329804885526
>   557893649662037092457130509980883789368448042961108430809620626
>   059287437887495827369474189818588006905358793385574832590121472
>   680866521970802708379837148646191567765584039175249171110593159
>   305029014037881475265618958103073425958633163441030267478942720
>   703134493880117805010891574606323700178176718412858948243785754
>   898788359757528163558061136758276299059029113119763557411729353
>   915848889261125855717014320045292143759177464380434854573300054
>   940683350937992500211758727939459249163046465047204851616590276
>   724564411037216844005877918224201569391107769029955591465502737
>   961776799311859881060956465198859727495735498887960494256488224
>   613682478900505821893815926193600121890632

Comment: As David is implying, pow(n, 1/3) will give you the cubic (i.e. 3rd) root of n.

Comment: No it won't, since 1/3 == 0 in python < 3.

Comment: (But it won't be what the OP wanted, either).

Comment: Py3 doesn't have integer limitations... they can grow forever until memory runs out. I tested on my installation. That's a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make it run slightly faster by avoiding the while loops in favor of setting low to 10 ** (len(str(x)) / n) and high to low * 10.  Probably better is to replace the len(str(x)) with the bitwise length and using a bit shift.  Based on my tests, I estimate a 5% speedup from the first and a 25% speedup from the second.  If the ints are big enough, this might matter (and the speedups may vary).  Don't trust my code without testing it carefully.  I did some basic testing but may have missed an edge case.  Also, these speedups vary with the number chosen.

If the actual data you're using is much bigger than what you posted here, this change may be worthwhile.

```
from timeit import Timer

def find_invpow(x,n):
    """Finds the integer component of the n'th root of x,
    an integer such that y ** n <= x < (y + 1) ** n.
    """
    high = 1
    while high ** n < x:
        high *= 2
    low = high/2
    while low < high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if low < mid and mid**n < x:
            low = mid
        elif high > mid and mid**n > x:
            high = mid
        else:
            return mid
    return mid + 1

def find_invpowAlt(x,n):
    """Finds the integer component of the n'th root of x,
    an integer such that y ** n <= x < (y + 1) ** n.
    """
    low = 10 ** (len(str(x)) / n)
    high = low * 10

    while low < high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if low < mid and mid**n < x:
            low = mid
        elif high > mid and mid**n > x:
            high = mid
        else:
            return mid
    return mid + 1

x = 237734537465873465
n = 5
tests = 10000

print "Norm", Timer('find_invpow(x,n)', 'from __main__ import find_invpow, x,n').timeit(number=tests)
print "Alt", Timer('find_invpowAlt(x,n)', 'from __main__ import find_invpowAlt, x,n').timeit(number=tests)
```

Norm 0.626754999161

Alt 0.566340923309

Comment: Your second function, find_invpowAlt, gives a wildly wrong answer for x=118997879821732370764604711647724283139870175351576755860556891902958645241483485254092600557474860904935286687480039428945219115513349647465379580432922136155355040992635166676363150438436216219094913514982415747153956476970303302126880391024128871557664284712411567099374094385902892603751471822837746770111, n=3

Comment: The line `low = high/2` should be `low = high // 2` if you actually want an integer out at the end.

Comment: I wrote it using `low = high/2` intentionally, as I directly copied that answer from [Markus's Code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/356206/2) as a means of benchmarking it when compared to my proposed improvement.  I'll note that since then, Markus has updated his code to correct a bug and tzs has replied to my code that it also has a bug.  However, I don't actually remember the details of the problem nor of my solution, so I no longer feel competent to address these shortcomings.

Answer (score 30):

If it's a REALLY big number. You could use a binary search.

```
def find_invpow(x,n):
    """Finds the integer component of the n'th root of x,
    an integer such that y ** n <= x < (y + 1) ** n.
    """
    high = 1
    while high ** n <= x:
        high *= 2
    low = high/2
    while low < high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if low < mid and mid**n < x:
            low = mid
        elif high > mid and mid**n > x:
            high = mid
        else:
            return mid
    return mid + 1
```

For example:

```
>>> x = 237734537465873465
>>> n = 5
>>> y = find_invpow(x,n)
>>> y
2986
>>> y**n <= x <= (y+1)**n
True
>>>
>>> x = 119680039660309643568856114803834088331723464504673392511960931441>
>>> n = 45
>>> y = find_invpow(x,n)
>>> y
227661383982863143360L
>>> y**n <= x < (y+1)**n
True
>>> find_invpow(y**n,n) == y
True
>>>
```

Comment: It will still fail for numbers > ~10**1000. Changing `mid = (low + high) // 2` to `mid = int((low + high) // 2) + 1` would fix that.

Comment: Downvoted because it has bugs. I tried `find_invpow(64, 3)` and got 3, even though the result should have been 4.

Comment: The line `low = high/2` should be `low = high // 2` if you actually want an integer out at the end.

Comment: Dichotomic search seems a pretty slow method. Prefer Newton's iterations, which double the number of exact digit every time. To find a very accurate starting value, use floating-point.

Answer (score 17):

[Gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) is a C-coded Python extension module that wraps the GMP library to provide to Python code fast multiprecision arithmetic (integer, rational, and float), random number generation, advanced number-theoretical functions, and more.

Includes a `root` function:

> x.root(n): returns a 2-element tuple (y,m), such that y is the
>   (possibly truncated) n-th root of x; m, an ordinary Python int,
>   is 1 if the root is exact (x==y**n), else 0.  n must be an ordinary
>   Python int, >=0.

For example, 20th root:

```
>>> import gmpy
>>> i0=11968003966030964356885611480383408833172346450467339251 
>>> m0=gmpy.mpz(i0)
>>> m0
mpz(11968003966030964356885611480383408833172346450467339251L)
>>> m0.root(20)
(mpz(567), 0)
```

Comment: With `gmpy2` this results in: `'mpz' object has no attribute 'root'`.

Comment: gmpy2 uses a new mpfr type based on the MPFR library.  gmpy2.root(x, n) -> mpfr

Return n-th root of x. The result always an 'mpfr'.

Comment: @Zelphir gmpy2 has `gmpy2.iroot` to compute integer roots.

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for something standard, fast to write with high precision. I would use decimal and adjust the precision (getcontext().prec) to at least the length of x.

### Code (Python 3.0)

```
from decimal import *

x =   '11968003966030964356885611480383408833172346450467339251\
196093144141045683463085291115677488411620264826942334897996389\
485046262847265769280883237649461122479734279424416861834396522\
819159219215308460065265520143082728303864638821979329804885526\
557893649662037092457130509980883789368448042961108430809620626\
059287437887495827369474189818588006905358793385574832590121472\
680866521970802708379837148646191567765584039175249171110593159\
305029014037881475265618958103073425958633163441030267478942720\
703134493880117805010891574606323700178176718412858948243785754\
898788359757528163558061136758276299059029113119763557411729353\
915848889261125855717014320045292143759177464380434854573300054\
940683350937992500211758727939459249163046465047204851616590276\
724564411037216844005877918224201569391107769029955591465502737\
961776799311859881060956465198859727495735498887960494256488224\
613682478900505821893815926193600121890632'

minprec = 27
if len(x) > minprec: getcontext().prec = len(x)
else:                getcontext().prec = minprec

x = Decimal(x)
power = Decimal(1)/Decimal(3)

answer = x**power
ranswer = answer.quantize(Decimal('1.'), rounding=ROUND_UP)

diff = x - ranswer**Decimal(3)
if diff == Decimal(0):
    print("x is the cubic number of", ranswer)
else:
    print("x has a cubic root of ", answer)
```

### Answer

x is the cubic number of 22873918786185635329056863961725521583023133411
451452349318109627653540670761962215971994403670045614485973722724603798
107719978813658857014190047742680490088532895666963698551709978502745901
704433723567548799463129652706705873694274209728785041817619032774248488
2965377218610139128882473918261696612098418

Answer (score 3):

Oh, for numbers *that* big, you would use the decimal module.

ns: your number as a string

```
ns = "11968003966030964356885611480383408833172346450467339251196093144141045683463085291115677488411620264826942334897996389485046262847265769280883237649461122479734279424416861834396522819159219215308460065265520143082728303864638821979329804885526557893649662037092457130509980883789368448042961108430809620626059287437887495827369474189818588006905358793385574832590121472680866521970802708379837148646191567765584039175249171110593159305029014037881475265618958103073425958633163441030267478942720703134493880117805010891574606323700178176718412858948243785754898788359757528163558061136758276299059029113119763557411729353915848889261125855717014320045292143759177464380434854573300054940683350937992500211758727939459249163046465047204851616590276724564411037216844005877918224201569391107769029955591465502737961776799311859881060956465198859727495735498887960494256488224613682478900505821893815926193600121890632"
from decimal import Decimal
d = Decimal(ns)
one_third = Decimal("0.3333333333333333")
print d ** one_third
```

and the answer is: 2.287391878618402702753613056E+305

TZ pointed out that this isn't accurate... and he's right.  Here's my test.

```
from decimal import Decimal

def nth_root(num_decimal, n_integer):
    exponent = Decimal("1.0") / Decimal(n_integer)
    return num_decimal ** exponent

def test():
    ns = "11968003966030964356885611480383408833172346450467339251196093144141045683463085291115677488411620264826942334897996389485046262847265769280883237649461122479734279424416861834396522819159219215308460065265520143082728303864638821979329804885526557893649662037092457130509980883789368448042961108430809620626059287437887495827369474189818588006905358793385574832590121472680866521970802708379837148646191567765584039175249171110593159305029014037881475265618958103073425958633163441030267478942720703134493880117805010891574606323700178176718412858948243785754898788359757528163558061136758276299059029113119763557411729353915848889261125855717014320045292143759177464380434854573300054940683350937992500211758727939459249163046465047204851616590276724564411037216844005877918224201569391107769029955591465502737961776799311859881060956465198859727495735498887960494256488224613682478900505821893815926193600121890632"
    nd = Decimal(ns)
    cube_root = nth_root(nd, 3)
    print (cube_root ** Decimal("3.0")) - nd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

It's off by about 10**891

Comment: Um. This could work, but it's not accurate. Using your terms, and if answer equals d**one_third, then how much (answer**3 - d) should be?

Comment: Decimal is about as accurate as you need it to be... my 0.333 string is just for brevity.

Comment: tz... you're correct.  It' way off...  oh well.  The newton's method above does rock though!

Answer (score 3):

I may suggest four methods for solving your task. First is based on [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Second is based on [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). Third is based on [Shifting n-th Root Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_nth_root_algorithm). Fourth is called by me Chord-Tangent method described by me in [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et9O0.jpg).

Binary Search was already implemented in many answers above. I just introduce here my own vision of it and its implementation.

As alternative I also implement Optimized Binary Search method (marked `Opt`). This method just starts from range `[hi / 2, hi)` where `hi` is equal to `2^(num_bit_length / k)` if we're computing k-th root.

Newton's Method is new here, as I see it wasn't implemented in other answers. It is usually considered to be faster than Binary Search, although my own timings in code below don't show any speedup. Hence this method here is just for reference/interest.

Shifting Method is 30-50% faster than optimized binary search method, and should be even faster if implemented in C++, because C++ has fast 64 bit arithemtics which is partially used in this method.

Chord-Tangent Method:

[image]

Chord-Tangent Method is invented by me [on piece of paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et9O0.jpg) (see image above), it is inspired and is an improvement of Newton method. Basically I draw a [Chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(geometry)) and a [Tangent Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent) and find intersection with horizontal line `y = n`, these two intersections form lower and upper bound approximations of location of root solution `(x0, n)` where `n = x0 ^ k`. This method appeared to be fastest of all, while all other methods do more than 2000 iterations, this method does just 8 iterations, for the case of 8192-bit numbers. So this method is **200-300x** times faster than previous (by speed) Shifting Method.

As an example I generate really huge random integer of 8192 bits in size. And measure timings of finding cubic root with both methods.

In `test()` function you can see that I passed `k = 3` as root's power (cubic root), you can pass any power instead of 3.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xRfbbqNG9N1fcaRVa4jxLanarhXnIa361t2H3beqGmEztqc2A4JJYr4@PWcOl8Hg2Km2WpQY5nDud9LC7BJ99/oayQ2slA6zQuQyzNY7byW3SgcgdRTAJoCbALQyMoMl/DX7218MAK@XnTpIsJhwT6gMpssiIyaMljCvobGKkAHzhhFR@PDw4CCoDWw8xPIbTnQxwdLSjxx0echlGxNZMp6FZtI8ZZrJB4OOkWJvdiJLEuOhpXtr5LPMVkkukccfITIv9fgAO2PSfDGdSj15UXuVykiFkyTbTuk0fWxxDQ/bJFNmFw9qT7DbSp1yPLWdPUPvkmEBHMJ4FYVASi3sL9zcwB69q5sA2Ls/KP1Vaty4Ic2UNt6QdYIvVgIQSWhUovPFMKij47teQsX6fJSk5rv4aafwMIf7e/D0ZKWMOEi9NTvPh@kUPTKGue8kIWKzo9A9l7IQce/vK0BfOBCBsjJAzP8vIp9T866oaPliEv3NQvHJsvvh9pdcxBK7ABfMBrmUBh8XcGRTx6Dty6j9dg83jOE50TgGkB4dxwRwi2h4q8LK4QpXuZcekeyIDQDmlyKGqEs41kckXGKfONpUiOjhkuvZWvjTWvqm22OlMej4@4wiPyVaBvaXvZNkoAA7URbqrfTGtwHcOZ2KKMgwVAiLWfm@29YsR5VbZoB8njGDCNZuXy3p@PTspgJxJQTOh3ynNkbp7TfLiC8VQ10yPCnQR4FVSMXy80/2zKoFUCAIG9iMkaqiZWyG7SvKkgUmVfUiDvM9jQSmYUSf0qm3J/RF4bQ7jGp5lJSUIc45gLH9d6IWHtJdSCpoKnoP@0ithw8/VjrW6I@C7C1OTCytKawthS0b37HIxclELTFrGT1iVdr8RIuCRYwcNoNmRJqw08jQ1se6gxHGAjwyYGQPft0yT0WddrY6IHQVAWQ2lhWfwDVrDF5XxJgl@INLdVrl4KVKdcui4HpY75IsEoZyQl8/sb7T1Onrs1f32KaQ1SQ34Xo/UfH2KZusk3gqzcfPs8k/6Za7sSjXuKPgxciZbBahqBCKEgF7F4P8wD7TitZU3bpYo9V16Vk/3c2cYsLQsqhxJZt8Mz/Z5jIZ7i94CxnNFmjp7wm0x2ZuZEpvtZSRjFp8j6LcLyvRI1bmZMdkuxmVTKR1s/USufP7BzeqjRS7E1cOs/QBE7Q30c5u2opI6flzHD5gGykdWWJiBoJ34lyf@9YpjnYxxg/N3BQsr/JOm/Smhz0mfUePphFYduRCB1gVoJ3YwpGi62lNj@4WXz9wCfdRtnTr6OWIb9p6nsvM1CwxC2vNAvBKcNAA/UEnRFXRdJEdF1xbP45ORVMZ2tWlZkZ/fQ6v6UnWgyXmknRUQ7o3vnH8UlMro3Kgvrg@/UYqwleWcc0WVW0swvn0MjI3XtkrVJwmaAm2kSiJUXsVS2WaEa@zJ037wp09lcvDr/OPt/wWD0w5oZvTi7x67gfcxO1kbfh2JmTLO3fukPiaPUmmXHWITj@JzhCuaX52t/Yz2JQ9vTvdGXxZZ2bfzDtDVGYQbak0qlc@JeEM0Is1bG1h8xYs6oFJhmEOWk4BWGK@RXyT5aDmLPIHZ7@FMP5oNaVRljzpyON8mPDN43G4eCtyGG/9FK94ZaHkoU5oH/jlMJfr4RsK0MfYf1GikwnvV6T9aXKdEn1Z9X7Jp8vWdbL7c/T90nt7ynUqvJH2V@oxwGYnhA5jKQQslzAUuOUrLcSQ@xP3qsHr678)

```py
def binary_search(begin, end, f, *, niter = [0]):
    while begin < end:
        niter[0] += 1
        mid = (begin + end) >> 1
        if f(mid):
            begin = mid + 1
        else:
            end = mid
    return begin

def binary_search_kth_root(n, k, *, verbose = False):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm
    niter = [0]
    res = binary_search(0, n + 1, lambda root: root ** k < n, niter = niter)
    if verbose:
        print('Binary Search iterations:', niter[0])
    return res

def binary_search_opt_kth_root(n, k, *, verbose = False):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm
    niter = [0]
    hi = 1 << (n.bit_length() // k - 1)
    while hi ** k <= n:
        niter[0] += 1
        hi <<= 1
    res = binary_search(hi >> 1, hi, lambda root: root ** k < n, niter = niter)
    if verbose:
        print('Binary Search Opt iterations:', niter[0])
    return res

def newton_kth_root(n, k, *, verbose = False):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method
    f = lambda x: x ** k - n
    df = lambda x: k * x ** (k - 1)
    x, px, niter = n, 2 * n, [0]
    while abs(px - x) > 1:
        niter[0] += 1
        px = x
        x -= f(x) // df(x)
    if verbose:
        print('Newton Method iterations:', niter[0])
    mini, minv = None, None
    for i in range(-2, 3):
        v = abs(f(x + i))
        if minv is None or v < minv:
            mini, minv = i, v
    return x + mini

def shifting_kth_root(n, k, *, verbose = False):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_nth_root_algorithm
    B_bits = 64
    
    r, y = 0, 0
    B = 1 << B_bits
    Bk_bits = B_bits * k
    Bk_mask = (1 << Bk_bits) - 1
    niter = [0]
    
    for i in range((n.bit_length() + Bk_bits - 1) // Bk_bits - 1, -1, -1):
        alpha = (n >> (i * Bk_bits)) & Bk_mask
        B_y = y << B_bits
        Bk_yk = (y ** k) << Bk_bits
        Bk_r_alpha = (r << Bk_bits) + alpha
        Bk_yk_Bk_r_alpha = Bk_yk + Bk_r_alpha
        beta = binary_search(1, B, lambda beta: (B_y + beta) ** k <= Bk_yk_Bk_r_alpha, niter = niter) - 1
        y, r = B_y + beta, Bk_r_alpha - ((B_y + beta) ** k - Bk_yk)

    if verbose:
        print('Shifting Method iterations:', niter[0])

    return y

def chord_tangent_kth_root(n, k, *, verbose = False):
    niter = [0]
    hi = 1 << (n.bit_length() // k - 1)
    while hi ** k <= n:
        niter[0] += 1
        hi <<= 1
    f = lambda x: x ** k
    df = lambda x: k * x ** (k - 1)
    # https://i.stack.imgur.com/et9O0.jpg
    x_begin, x_end = hi >> 1, hi
    y_begin, y_end = f(x_begin), f(x_end)
    for icycle in range(1 << 30):
        if x_end - x_begin <= 1:
            break
        niter[0] += 1
        if 0: # Do Binary Search step if needed
            x_mid = (x_begin + x_end) >> 1
            y_mid = f(x_mid)
            if y_mid > n:
                x_end, y_end = x_mid, y_mid
            else:
                x_begin, y_begin = x_mid, y_mid
        # (y_end - y_begin) / (x_end - x_begin) = (n - y_begin) / (x_n - x_begin) ->
        x_n = x_begin + (n - y_begin) * (x_end - x_begin) // (y_end - y_begin)
        y_n = f(x_n)
        tangent_x = x_n + (n - y_n) // df(x_n) + 1
        
        chord_x = x_n + (n - y_n) * (x_end - x_n) // (y_end - y_n)
        
        assert chord_x <= tangent_x, (chord_x, tangent_x)
        x_begin, x_end = chord_x, tangent_x
        y_begin, y_end = f(x_begin), f(x_end)
        assert y_begin <= n, (chord_x, y_begin, n, n - y_begin)
        assert y_end > n, (icycle, tangent_x - binary_search_kth_root(n, k), y_end, n, y_end - n)
    if verbose:
        print('Chord Tangent Method iterations:', niter[0])
    return x_begin

def test():
    import random, timeit
    
    nruns = 3
    bits = 8192
    n = random.randrange(1 << (bits - 1), 1 << bits)
    
    a = binary_search_kth_root(n, 3, verbose = True)
    b = binary_search_opt_kth_root(n, 3, verbose = True)
    c = newton_kth_root(n, 3, verbose = True)
    d = shifting_kth_root(n, 3, verbose = True)
    e = chord_tangent_kth_root(n, 3, verbose = True)
    assert abs(a - b) <= 0 and abs(a - c) <= 1 and abs(a - d) <= 1 and abs(a - e) <= 1, (a - b, a - c, a - d, a - e)

    print()
    print('Binary Search timing:', round(timeit.timeit(lambda: binary_search_kth_root(n, 3), number = nruns) / nruns, 3), 'sec')
    print('Binary Search Opt timing:', round(timeit.timeit(lambda: binary_search_opt_kth_root(n, 3), number = nruns) / nruns, 3), 'sec')
    print('Newton Method timing:', round(timeit.timeit(lambda: newton_kth_root(n, 3), number = nruns) / nruns, 3), 'sec')
    print('Shifting Method timing:', round(timeit.timeit(lambda: shifting_kth_root(n, 3), number = nruns) / nruns, 3), 'sec')
    print('Chord Tangent Method timing:', round(timeit.timeit(lambda: chord_tangent_kth_root(n, 3), number = nruns) / nruns, 3), 'sec')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Output:

```
Binary Search iterations: 8192
Binary Search Opt iterations: 2732
Newton Method iterations: 9348
Shifting Method iterations: 2752
Chord Tangent Method iterations: 8

Binary Search timing: 0.506 sec
Binary Search Opt timing: 0.05 sec
Newton Method timing: 2.09 sec
Shifting Method timing: 0.03 sec
Chord Tangent Method timing: 0.001 sec
```

Comment: Why are you assigning `niter` a default value?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly for your curiosity:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel_Lifting

This could be the technique that Maple would use to actually find the nth root of large numbers.

Pose the fact that `x^n - 11968003.... = 0 mod p`, and go from there...

Answer (score 1):

I came up with my own answer, which takes @Mahmoud Kassem's idea, simplifies the code, and makes it more reusable:

```
def cube_root(x):
    return decimal.Decimal(x) ** (decimal.Decimal(1) / decimal.Decimal(3))
```

I tested it in Python 3.5.1 and Python 2.7.8, and it seemed to work fine.

The result will have as many digits as specified by the decimal context the function is run in, which by default is 28 decimal places. According to the documentation for the `power` function in the `decimal` module, "[The result is well-defined but only “almost always correctly-rounded”.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context.power)". If you need a more accurate result, it can be done as follows:

```
with decimal.localcontext() as context:
    context.prec = 50
    print(cube_root(42))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use SymPy for this:

```
In [29]: n = 1196800396603096435688561148038340883317234645046733925119609314414104568346308529111567
    ...: 74884116202648269423348979963894850462628472657692808832376494611224797342794244168618343965
    ...: 22819159219215308460065265520143082728303864638821979329804885526557893649662037092457130509
    ...: 98088378936844804296110843080962062605928743788749582736947418981858800690535879338557483259
    ...: 01214726808665219708027083798371486461915677655840391752491711105931593050290140378814752656
    ...: 18958103073425958633163441030267478942720703134493880117805010891574606323700178176718412858
    ...: 94824378575489878835975752816355806113675827629905902911311976355741172935391584888926112585
    ...: 57170143200452921437591774643804348545733000549406833509379925002117587279394592491630464650
    ...: 47204851616590276724564411037216844005877918224201569391107769029955591465502737961776799311
    ...: 85988106095646519885972749573549888796049425648822461368247890050582189381592619360012189063
    ...: 2

In [30]: import sympy

In [31]: r = sympy.Integer(n) ** sympy.Rational(1, 3)

In [32]: print(r)
228739187861856353290568639617255215830231334114514523493181096276535406707619622159719944036700456144859737227246037981077199788136588570141900477426804900885328956669636985517099785027459017044337235675487994631296527067058736942742097287850418176190327742484882965377218610139128882473918261696612098418
```

This is just using SymPy's general symbolic expression simplification. The above will give an exact result if possible or otherwise an expression e.g.:

```
In [33]: r2 = sympy.Integer(10) ** sympy.Rational(1, 3)

In [34]: r2
Out[34]: 
3 ____
╲╱ 10 

In [35]: r2.evalf(50)
Out[35]: 2.1544346900318837217592935665193504952593449421921
```

SymPy also has a function specifically for computing the nth root of an integer as an integer:

```
In [38]: sympy.integer_nthroot(n, 3)
Out[38]: 
(228739187861856353290568639617255215830231334114514523493181096276535406707619622159719944036700456144859737227246037981077199788136588570141900477426804900885328956669636985517099785027459017044337235675487994631296527067058736942742097287850418176190327742484882965377218610139128882473918261696612098418,
 True)
```

The `True` here indicates that the result is an exact cube root. When an exact root is not possible this function will return the floor of the cube root:

```
In [39]: sympy.integer_nthroot(10, 3)
Out[39]: (2, False)
```

In other words 2 is the greatest integer such that `2**3 <= 10` but the False indicates that `2**3 != 10`.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Python, `1/3` is equal to 0.  In Python 3.0, `1/3` is equal to 0.33333333333 (and `1//3` is equal to 0).

So, either change your code to use `1/3.0` or switch to Python 3.0 .

Comment: As far as I can tell, there was no indication that it used Python 2.

Comment: @SolomonUckoI This question and answer were both posted only 1 week after python 3 was released.

Answer (score -1):

Try converting the exponent to a floating number, as the default behaviour of / in Python is integer division

n**(1/float(3))

Comment: n**(1.0/3) will do the job too

Comment: OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float, it just would not work cause the huge number cannot be converted

Comment: As far as I can tell, there was no indication that it used Python 2.

Answer (score -3):

Well, if you're not particularly worried about precision, you could convert it to a sting, chop off some digits, use the exponent function, and then multiply the result by the root of how much you chopped off.

E.g. 32123 is about equal to 32 * 1000, the cubic root is about equak to cubic root of 32 * cubic root of 1000.  The latter can be calculated by dividing the number of 0s by 3.

This avoids the need for the use of extension modules.

Comment: I'm worried about precision because i know this number, for example is the third power of another integer. (And of course i need to know this integer) :)

Comment: Also, converting to string might become problematic with huge numbers.

Comment: @Attila: Not in the definition of huge he gave in the post.  Also, not sure exactly what format he is accepting input in, but the basic idea of truncation will work in most formats.

Comment: He has working code, just _the **problem** is precision_