# Python math.sqrt loss precision

Tags: python

I tried to get sqrt value of a long int

```
from math import sqrt
print sqrt(410241186411534352) 

<< 640500731.0
```

It returned 640500731.0, which indeed is 640500730.999999993... in precision. How to fix that?

**I solved it according to @DSM and @Rob's reply, thank you so much.**

```
from math import sqrt
from decimal import Decimal
print Decimal(410241186411534352).sqrt()
```

Comment: If you need an integer sqrt function, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390807/integer-square-root-in-python) for several options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 100
>>> a=decimal.Decimal(410241186411534352)**decimal.Decimal(.5)
>>> print a
640500730.9999999929742468943411712910588335443486974564849183256021518032770726219326459594197730639
>>> print a*a
410241186411534352.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Python math library functions are thin wrappers around the C math library functions, so Python is converting the long integer into a double-sized floating point number before doing the computation. If you want genuine multiprecision arithmetic in Python, you could try [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/).

Comment: Any change I could solve this problem using pure python, without some other packages?

Comment: @AaronJiang: you could use the `decimal` module.

Comment: The `decimal` module is nicely demonstrated by @Robᵩ in another answer.

Comment: @AaronJiang: Glad to help. If `decimal` works for you, you might want to tick @Robᵩ's answer as the correct one.