# Truncation error in taking square root in python

Tags: python, rsa, truncate, prime-factoring, square-root

I'm trying to use Fermat's factorization method
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method
to factor a RSA exercise with `n = pq = 17113393402958118715148546526344227921781458985077442510282855190555424972779474416264134494113`

Here's my python code:

```
    def isSquare(x):
      return pow(int(sqrt(x)),2) - x == 0

n = 17113393402958118715148546526344227921781458985077442510282855190555424972779474416264134494113  

for i in xrange(10):
  print isSquare(n+i*i)
```

When I execute, it prints all `True`s, which isn't correct. I think it's truncation error in python. How should I deal with it? Thanks.

```
def isqrt(n):
    x = n
    y = (x + n // x) // 2
    while y < x:
        x = y
        y = (x + n // x) // 2
    return x

print isqrt(99999999999**2)
for i in xrange(130000,140000):
  if isqrt(n + i*i) ** 2 == n + i*i:
    print isqrt(n + i*i)
print "done"
```

Comment: `math.sqrt()` operates on `float` (which cannot hold the range you seem to need).  I'd say use `Decimal`, or better yet one of the math libraries..

Comment: You can use the well-known `SymPy` library to do that: http://sympy.org/fr/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

math.sqrt uses floating point numbers, which are inexact.

The easiest way is probably to change sqrt to integer isqrt function, and you can just copy decent isqrt implementation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391420/220700

Comment: So why does this work better
 
    def isqrt(n):
        i = int(sqrt(n) + 0.5)
            if i**2 == n:
                return i
  #raise ValueError('input was not a perfect square')
            else:
                return 0

Comment: I meant code from the best answer, not code from the question. I've corrected the link to make it more precise.

Comment: Thank you, Sergey. What does // do?

Comment: "//" is integer division. 7 // 2 is 3. "/" can work as integer division in early Python versions, but in newer versions 7 / 2 is 3.5

Comment: so does // apply in python 2.7?

Comment: In python 2.7 you can use "//" or "/" for integer division. But it's better to use "//" to communicate the intention and to make the code future-proof.

Comment: **Sorry somehow the format doesn't work here. I have reproduced this code in my original question.

Does this still work in the following range for i?
    def isqrt(n):
        x = n
        y = (x + n // x) // 2
        while y < x:
            x = y
            y = (x + n // x) // 2
        return x
    
    print isqrt(99999999999**2)
    for i in xrange(130000,140000):
      if isqrt(n + i*i) ** 2 == n + i*i:
        print isqrt(n + i*i)
    print "done"

Sorry somehow the format doesn't work here. I have reproduced this code in my original question.

Comment: isqrt linked from my answer will work for any arbitrary large integer numbers. The only limiting factor is available memory.

Comment: For large numbers, how efficient is this algorithm? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newton's method to find the integer square root of a number:

```
def isqrt(n):
    x = n
    y = (x + n // x) // 2
    while y < x:
        x = y
        y = (x + n // x) // 2
    return x
```

This returns the largest integer *x* such that *x* × *x* does not exceed *n*.

But it is highly unlikely that Fermat's method will be able to factor your 95-digit RSA semi-prime. You should look at the quadratic sieve or the number field sieve to factor a number of that size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make usage of sqrt() function out of module math. The code could look like:

```
import math
n = math.sqrt(int(raw_input("Enter a number\n")))
print n
```

Comment: This won't help for the large numbers the OP uses, because `math.sqrt` converts its argument to `float` first, and there is a rounding error there, and some very large integers are too large to fit into a `float`.