# Get ceiling of sqrt without float point. Python 3.7.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, math.sqrt

I need to get the ceiling of a square root, such as `10**10001` (10^10001). If I do:

```
from math import sqrt
print(int(sqrt(10**10001))+1)
```

I look, and it gives me an `OverflowError`.
More precisely, a

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File <stdin>, line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: int too large to convert to float.
```

I need a integer for an answer. The `OverflowError` is coming from the `math.sqrt(x)` function.
If anybody can help, it would be appreciated.

Comment: That's 1 with 10 thousand zeros. Why do you need a number that large?

Comment: I need to calculate extremely large numbers to see if they are prime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the sqrt function of math module for long numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150824/using-the-sqrt-function-of-math-module-for-long-numbers-in-python)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150824/using-the-sqrt-function-of-math-module-for-long-numbers-in-python. Try `import decimal` `print(int(decimal.Decimal(10**10001).sqrt())+1)`

Comment: 1. The question does not answer it. I am using regular integers.

Comment: 2. Your method doesn't work! It gives me the round logarithm of the answer! (317)

Comment: The question says ``print(int(sqrt(10*10001))+1)``, which is very much computable and prints ``317``. Is that a typo?

Comment: `math.sqrt` works with `float`. Given an `int`, it will convert some `int` to a `float` at some point. Python's `float` gets as large as 1.797e308, so 1e10001 is way too big for it (just as the error message says). You will need a different data type and a sqrt function that will work with that data type. I'm a bit confused why you insist on outputting an integer because sqrt(1e10001)=sqrt(10*1e10000)=sqrt(10)*1e5000 doesn't seem like an integer.

Answer (score -3):

the math module has a ceil and floor function

try print(math.ceil(math.sqrt(NUMBER)))

Comment: Int too large to convert to float. Again, the sqrt function! I need to calculate the sqrt of `10**10001` or 1 followed by 10,001 zeroes.

Comment: try math.ceil(math.sqrt(10)**10001) then. should fix that