# Finding sqrt of big integers in python

Tags: python, math, sqrt

I have problems with rounding big numbers. My code:

```
import math
n = int(input())
print (int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n))))
```

Input:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Output:

```
99999999999999997748809823456034029568
```

How can i solve the problem? Sorry for my English!!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390807/integer-square-root-in-python

Comment: Use the [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).