# How can I check for a perfect square in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to check whether a number is a perfect square.

This is my code:

```
def is_square(x)
  return true if
  math.sqrt(x).is_a? Integer
end
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimization for finding perfect-square algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896936/optimization-for-finding-perfect-square-algorithm)

Comment: `Math` should be capitalized, like `return true if Math.sqrt(x).is_a?(Integer`) . Also the name of the method could better to be `is_square?(x)`

Comment: Thank you. 
I have just done that but it's still returning the following error messages:#
main.rb:4:in `is_square'
main.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in 
'
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:180:in `wrap_error'
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:72:in `it'
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:206:in `it'
main.rb:10:in `block in 
'
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:55:in `block in describe'
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:46:in `measure'
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:51:in `describe'
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:202:in `describe'
main.rb:9:in `
'

Comment: What are you using to run the program?

Comment: It's on codewars.  It's still full of errors even when I divide by 1 to avoid getting a float... Don't worry, your answer was still very useful and helped me to learn more about coding!

Comment: What do you mean "isn't working"?

Comment: Can you explain what "it doesn't work" means? Do you get an error? If yes, what is the error? Do you get a wrong result? If yes, what is the result you get and what is the result you expect (and why do you expect to get that result)? Did you read what the documentation of `Math::sqrt` says about what it returns?

Answer (score 8):

1. You mispelled `Math`, which is constant holding module designed for mathematic operations.
2. `Math.sqrt(9)` also returns float, so this isn't gonna work either. But you can check the remainder of division by `1`.
3. Apart from this, the style in which you wrote this method is really bad, it can be written much better.

To summarize, I would do something like this:

```
def is_square?(x)
  (Math.sqrt(x) % 1).zero?
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I have only recently started learning, hence the style errors.

Comment: The original version of the [Pickaxe Book](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0) is available [for free](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) and is a great introduction to the Ruby language and its style conventions.

Answer (score 3):

The result is aways a float:

```
Math.sqrt(4)
# => 2.0

Math.sqrt(4).class
#  => Float
```

You need to check if the result is a number without decimal points:

```
def is_square(x)
  Math.sqrt(x) % 1 == 0
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to capitalise `math` to `Math`.

The other problem with this code is the return value of `Math.sqrt`. Suppose you supply `4` as the value of `x`. `Math.sqrt` *always* returns a Float (a decimal), even if that Float happens to be a round number, so the result would be `2.0`. As far as Ruby is concerned, and most programming languages for that matter, `2.0` isn't an Integer. It's still a Float, just one which doesn't have any decimal portion.

The easiest way to check if a Float is an integer is to mod it by 1 (that is, divide it by 1 and get the remainder), which may be done using `%`, and then check that this remainder is 0.

```
def is_square(x)
  return true if Math.sqrt(x) % 1 == 0
end
```

This function still isn't perfect though; it returns `true` for a square and `nil` for a non-square. It'd make more sense for it to return `false` for a non-square instead.

This can be done by removing the `if`, and simply returning the result of the conditional. Also, `return` in Ruby isn't required for the last statement of a block.

```
def is_square(x)
  Math.sqrt(x) % 1 == 0
end
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is a very detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Ruby 2.5 the Integer class has [sqrt](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-c-sqrt) , which returns the integer square root.

```
def is_square?(x)
  Integer.sqrt(x) ** 2  == x
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `Math#sqrt` will never be an integer type, even for perfect squares. In general, type checks are not very helpful in Ruby.

Instead, there are a couple strategies you can use to determine if a number is integer in Ruby.

### Compare against coerced value:

```
x == x.to_int
```

### Check if the denominator is 1:

```
x.denominator == 1
```

### Check if the remainder modulo 1 is 0:

```
x % 1 == 0
```

---

As an aside, idiomatic Ruby also doesn't use prefixes like `is_`, but instead adds a suffix question mark to predicate methods:

```
def perfect_square?(x)
  # Implementation
end
```