# integer square root in Scala

Tags: scala, integer, sqrt

my problem is creating a sqrt function for integer via Scala

f.e.: sqrt ( 26 ) = 6 , s² >= n 
sqrt (0) = 0, sqrt (1) = 1, sqrt (2) = 2, sqrt (3) = 2, sqrt (4) = 2, sqrt (5) to sqrt (9) = 3 ....

here is my code i came up with:

```
def sqrt (n: Int): Int = {          

  def sq (a: Int, n: Int): Int = {
    val b = (a + n) / 2
    val c = (b + n / b) / 2
    if (b * b == n) b 
    else if (b * b < n) b + 1
    else c 
  }
  if (n == 0 || n == 1) n else sq (0 , n)       
}
```

however it doesn't work with all the numbers n >= 0. 
f.e.: for 6 its 2, how do i tweak my formula?

Comment: So you whan to return result as integer as well ??

Comment: The square root of 6 **is** 2, if the result is supposed to be an `Int`.  What result did you expect?

Comment: my expected result is 3, because it needs to meet the condition of s² >= n.
because 2² !>= 6.

Comment: Please write the test cases for the task first. It will be much easier to test if you get what expected.

Comment: edited my question: the sqrt for 10 to 16 should be 4, 17 to 25 it's 5 and so on. and yes everything in integer :/

Comment: The question title mentions recursion. There is no recursion in the code.  Is the title wrong or is the code supposed to be recursive? And why is the zero value `a` a passed parameter? It's always zero. Why pass it in?

Comment: my title is wrong, sorry for that, edited. it's given in our task to create a function with sqr ( a: Int, n: Int) and return sqr (0,n), i know its useless but my professor want it that way. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your assignment makes no sense. The simple solution is `math.sqrt(n).ceil.toInt`. Done.

Comment: This is to learn scala. Its a classical task to learn scala. See my updated answer below. But still not sure why you need function signature to be Int -> Int?

Comment: my professor probably want us to learn it via the newton method. here is a link i found using python [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390807/integer-square-root-in-python?rq=1) it is similar to what i did but, he is using a while - loop, which we are not allowed to use.

Comment: It is a newtons method below:) try just spend some time playing with the code below. Try different corner cases etc.

Comment: sorry but I am still beginner level so your code doesnt make any sense to me, and we are still using Kojo in school so thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Try change type to Double. Result should be obvious.

```
 object Math {

  def roundUp(d: Double) = math.ceil(d).toInt

  def abs(x: Double) = if (x < 0) -x else x

  def sqrt(x: Double) = roundUp( sqrtIter(1.0, x) )

  def sqrtIter(guess: Double, x: Double): Double =
    if (isGoodEnough(guess, x)) guess
    else sqrtIter(improve(guess, x), x)

  def isGoodEnough(guess: Double, x: Double) =
    abs(guess * guess - x) < .01

  def improve(guess: Double, x: Double) =
    (guess + x / guess) / 2
}

val r = Math.sqrt(24)
```

Comment: sorry but I have to use integer instead of double :/ thanks anyways

Comment: So, please update you question with requirements. Why you need int?

Comment: i need it for a homework, so the task is to do it in integer, i wrote my requirements in my question though.

Comment: The code above used for learning scala for education purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def sqrt (n: Int): Int = {

    def sq (a: Int, n: Int): Int = if (a * a >= n) a else sq (a+1 , n)

    if (sq (0 , n) * sq (0 , n) >= n) sq (0 , n) else sqrt (sq (0 , n))
    }
```

here is an easy and nice solution.

Comment: The last line is pointless. The `if` condition is never `false` so the `else` clause is never executed.

Comment: `def sqrt(n: Int): Int = (0 to n).dropWhile(x => x*x < n).head`

Comment: @manonmars Your solution doesn't properly handle negative numbers. Here it is Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/EInJFwJ6Rj2f1ydAW4yZiQ

Comment: @jwvh Your solution creates a `NoSuchElementException` when passed negative numbers. Here it is in Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BBPVTjA4RVGoIAHmL1TQZw

Answer (score 0):

I have added minor improvements to Pavel's Code: `roundUp` function does not really add up and it gives the wrong results. As square root values will mostly contain decimals, I have limited the decimal by 2 digits.

```
def trim(d:Double) = "%1.2f".format(d)

def sqrt(x: Double) =  trim( sqrtIter(1.0, x) ) //(replace /**roundUp**/ with trim)
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there are two solutions. One for the **floor** value (nearest `x: Int` where `x * x <= n`). And the other is the **ceiling** value (nearest `x: Int` where `x * x >= n`).

In your specific case, it appears you are asking for the ceiling.

---

**Floor:**

```scala
def squareRootFloor(value: Int): Option[Int] =
  if (value > -1)
    Some(
      if (value < 4)
        if (value < 2)
          value
        else
          1
      else {
        def recursive(factor: Int = 2, sqHigh: Int = 9): Int =
          if (value < sqHigh)
            factor
          else
            if (value == sqHigh)
              factor + 1
            else {
              val newFactorHigh = factor + 2
              recursive(factor + 1, newFactorHigh * newFactorHigh)
            }
        recursive()
      }
    )
  else
    None
```

[View/Execute in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7rNhKJEUTTGqhPZROn09GQ)

---

**Ceiling:**

```scala
def squareRootCeiling(value: Int): Option[Int] =
  if (value > -1)
    Some(
      if (value < 5)
        if (value < 2)
          value
        else
          2
      else {
        def recursive(factor: Int = 3, sqHigh: Int = 9): Int =
          if (value <= sqHigh)
            factor
          else {
            val newFactorHigh = factor + 1
            recursive(newFactorHigh, newFactorHigh * newFactorHigh)
          }
        recursive()
      }
    )
  else
    None
```

[View/Execute in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/wxnnMHN3TEa5zJCc5Bkz3Q)