# Handling large numbers python 2.7(runtime error)

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime

I have to make a program that finds the n-th element in the following endless sequence:

```
1 1 2 1 1 2 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 3 2 1......
```

So here you can see that 'center' increments by one and side elements of the 'center' reflect each other so we can break this sequence into small groups:

```
[1][121][12321][1234321].....
```

So the task is to find n-th element in the sequence given n. For example, we take 7 as input and must return 3, because the 7th element in sequence is 3. The problem here is that when n exceeds `10^15` my program shows runtime error, while input can be as large as `10^100000`. Here is my code:

```
n = int(input())
fin = n
number = long(1)
counter = long(0)
while n>0:
    n = n - number
    number = number+2
    counter = counter + 1
mid = long((counter-1)*(2+2*(counter-1))/2+1)

place = long(counter - abs(mid-fin))

if fin==0:
    print 0
else:
    print place
```

Comment: What happens for *center*s greater than 9 (assuming the numbers are in base9)? In other words what is the sequence following `12345678987654321`?

Comment: the same pattern: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have groups of numbers:

```
[1] [1 2 1] [1 2 3 2 1] ...
```

The overall amount of numbers in `k` groups is:

```
1 + 3 + 5 + ... + k*2-1
```

This is an arithmetic progression, its sum equals to

```
(1 + k*2-1) * k / 2 = k^2
```

Now let's find the number of full groups `k` that go before n-th number in the sequence.

```
k = ⌊sqrt(n-1)⌋
```

Now we know that our n-th number is in group number `k+1` that has `k*2+1` elements. Let's discard first `k` groups (they have `k^2` numbers), now we need to find the number with index `n-k^2`. And its value will be equal to `k+1 - |n-k^2 - (k+1)|`. For relatively small `n` we can use this code:

```
n = int(input())
k = int(math.sqrt(n-1))
print(k+1 - abs(n-k*k - (k+1)))
```

But seeing the `n <= 10^5000000` constraint we cannot simply use `math.sqrt`, we need other way of finding a square root of a large integer. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390807/integer-square-root-in-python) could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much! But can you explain this line: k = lsqrt(n-1)l?

Comment: @arkang, `sqrt` - is a square root of a number, `⌊x⌋` is `x` rounded down to the nearest integer

Comment: Unfortunately, this code does not work for certain inputs (which are unknown). But anyway thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @arkang, could you please give me a link to the problem? Maybe that sequence is zero-based?

Comment: I think link to the problem will be useless, because it is not on english), but I can tell you for sure that there is nothing else in the task and the sequence is not zero based.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162431/discussion-between-dale-and-ar-kang).

Comment: well, n is said to be 1<=n<=10^5000000, so it's not the case.