# Volume of pile of cubes

Tags: python, optimization

I'm trying a challenge. The idea is the following:

> "Your task is to construct a building which will be a pile of n cubes.
>   The cube at the bottom will have a volume of n^3, the cube above will
>   have volume of (n-1)^3 and so on until the top which will have a
>   volume of 1^3.
>
> You are given the total volume m of the building. Being given m can
>   you find the number n of cubes you will have to build? If no such n
>   exists return -1"

I saw that apparently:

**2**³ + 1 = 9 = 3² and 3 - 1 = **2**

**3**³ + 2³ + 1 = 36 = 6² and 6 - 3 = **3**

**4**³ + 3³ + 2³ + 1 = 100 = 10² and 10 - 6 = **4**

**5**³ + 4³ + 3³ + 2³ + 1 = 225 = 15² and 15 - 10 = **5**

**6**³ + 5³ + 4³ + 3³ + 2³ + 1 = 441 = 21² and 21 - 15 = **6**

So if I thought, **if I check that a certain number is a square root I can already exclude a few. Then I can start a variable at 1 at take that value (incrementing it) from the square root. The values will eventually match or the former square root will become negative.**

So I wrote this code:

```
def find_nb(m):
    x = m**0.5
    if (x%1==0):
        c = 1
        while (x != c and x > 0):
            x = x - c
            c = c + 1

        if (x == c):
            return c
        else:
            return -1
    return -1
```

Shouldn't this work? What am I missing?
I fail a third of the sample set, per example: 10170290665425347857 should be -1 and in my program it gives 79863.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3):

You're running up against a floating point precision problem.  Namely, we have

```
In [101]: (10170290665425347857)**0.5
Out[101]: 3189089316.0

In [102]: ((10170290665425347857)**0.5) % 1
Out[102]: 0.0
```

and so the inner branch is taken, even though it's not actually a square:

```
In [103]: int((10170290665425347857)**0.5)**2
Out[103]: 10170290665425347856
```

If you borrow one of the many integer square root options from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390807/integer-square-root-in-python) and verify that the sqrt squared gives the original number, you should be okay with your algorithm, at least if I haven't overlooked some corner case.

(Aside: you've already noticed the critical pattern.  The numbers 1, 3, 6, 10, 15.. are quite famous and have a formula of their own, which you could use to solve for whether there is such a number that works directly.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your answer is correct, but I have another solution to this problem which is waaaay easier

```
def max_level(remain_volume, currLevel):
    if remain_volume < currLevel ** 3:
        return -1
    if remain_volume == currLevel ** 3:
        return currLevel
    return max_level(remain_volume - currLevel**3, currLevel + 1)
```

And you find out the answer with `max_level(m, 0)`. It takes O(n) time and O(1) memory.

Comment: What happens when you try this solution on `10170290665425347857` (which is one of the values that the OP has to deal with)?

Answer (score 1):

[DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238421/7089239)'s answer is the one, but to add my two cents to improve the solution...

This expression from [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/) is for summing cube numbers:

```
sum of k**3 from k=1 to n:
    n**2 * (n+1)**2 / 4
```

This can of course be solved for the total volume in question. This here is one of the four solutions (requiring both n and v to be positive):

```
from math import sqrt

def n(v):
    return 1/2*(sqrt(8*sqrt(v) + 1) - 1)
```

But this function also returns `79863.0`. Now, if we sum all the cube numbers from 1 to n, we get a slightly different result due to the precision error:

```
v = 10170290665425347857
cubes = n(v)    # 79863
x = sum([i**3 for i in range(cubes+1)])

# x = 10170290665425347857, original
x  -> 10170290665425347856
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simple solution over this in PHP as per my requirement.

```php
function findNb($m) {
    $total = 0;
    $n = 0;

    while($total < $m) {
        $n += 1;
        $total += $n ** 3;
    }

    return $total === $m ? $n : -1;
}
```

In Python it would be:

```py
def find_nb(m):
    total = 0
    n = 0
    
    while (total < m):
        n = n + 1
        total = total + n ** 3
        
    return n if total == m else -1
```

Comment: Great, that's the answer :)

Comment: this is not a good solution for very large numbers