# a program to tell if a number is in fibonnicio series or not

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x=int(input("Enter that number:"))
i=0
m=0
def fact(n):
    return 1 if(n==1 or  n==0) else  n+fact(n-1)
while(1):
    m=fact(i)
    if(m==x):
        print("Yes this is a Fib")
        break
    if(m>x):
        print("This is not a Fib")
        break
    i+=1
```

this is a code that is used to show if a number is in a fibniocci series or not
can someone please tell me why this isnt working
This shows not a fibonnicio series even if a number is of the series

Comment: Where did you get `n+fact(n-1)` from? That is not the right recursive relationship. Also, `fact` is a strange name for a Fibonacci function -- did you just take the Factorial recursive relationship and replace the multiplication with a sum? What you calculate here is a Triangular number. Finally, the name is not fibonnicio, nor fibniocci. It's Fibonacci.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, *x* is a Fibonacci number if and only if either 5*x*<sup>2</sup> + 4 or 5*x*<sup>2</sup> − 4 is a perfect square ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Identification)). So the following algorithm tests if the input is a Fibonacci number without generating the whole sequence.

```py
import math

def is_square(x):
    return math.isqrt(x)**2 == x

def is_fibonacci(x):
    return is_square(5 * x**2 + 4) or is_square(5 * x**2 - 4)
```

The `math.isqrt` function exists in Python 3.8 and later. If using an earlier version, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390807/integer-square-root-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

This solution generates fibonacci sequence elements until the input equals one of the elements or the maximum element of the series is bigger than the input.

```
def isFib(num):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while (a <= num):
        if a == num:
            return True
        c = a+b
        a, b = b, c
    return False
```

The function can be used like this:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))

if isFib(x):
    print("The number you entered is part of the fibonacci sequence")
else:
    print("The number you entered is not part of the fibonacci sequence")
```

Comment: Thanks your code works perfectly.But can you please tell me why is my code not working.I think the logic is alright

Answer (score 0):

```
x=int(input("Enter that number:"))
i=0
m=0
def fact(n):
    return n if (n == 1 or n == 0) else fact(n - 1)+fact(n-2)
while(1):
    m=fact(i)
    if(m==x):
        print("Yes this is a Fib")
        break
    if(m>x):
        print("This is not a Fib")
        break
    i+=1
```

You have made some mistake in recursive function this is correct function to find feb number.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution with generators for a more iterative look and feel, and the fibonacci function is now reusable..

```
from itertools import takewhile

def fibonacci_series():
    """ fibonacci generator"""
    n1, n2 = 0, 1
    yield n1
    yield n2
    while True:
        cur = n1 + n2
        yield cur
        n1, n2 = n2, cur

def is_fib(value):
    return value in takewhile(lambda x: x <= value, fibonacci_series())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'is_fib(10) : {is_fib(10)}')
    print(f'is_fib(55) : {is_fib(55)}')
```