# Python squaring a square rooted number gives a different result although it should be the original number

Tags: python, rsa, primes, sqrt

Im working on RSA so I'm dealing with very large numbers (308 digits). In RSA a number N is the product of 2 primes p and q.

My N:

```
20254083928313901046078299908836135556415829454193867459405514358320313885965296062600909040071281223146837763723113350068483510086809787065437344845044248205975654791622356467691953988928774211033663314876745580293750456921795999384782277674803240671474563131823612882192899349325870727676292313218782419561
```

For the task I'm completing, I have been given N and am trying to find the primes p and q by implementing the method from this other post: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87417/finding-p-and-q-in-rsa-with-a-given-n-p-q10000.

When I square root N I get:

```
4500453746936401829977490795263804776361530154559603855210407318900755249674017838942492466443373259250056015327414929135301293865748694108450793034088448
```

And when I square this number I would expect to get N back, however, I get:

```
20254083928313899038600080147064458144896171593553283932412228091641105206147936089547530020826698707611325067918592113664216112071557998883417732874096894330570809935758528713783460134686650819864956839352000831110894044634083630533310853814832242550420262010702947392454262240042077177552422858018628042752
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this result so any help would greatly be appreciated.

My code:

```
modulo = 20254083928313901046078299908836135556415829454193867459405514358320313885965296062600909040071281223146837763723113350068483510086809787065437344845044248205975654791622356467691953988928774211033663314876745580293750456921795999384782277674803240671474563131823612882192899349325870727676292313218782419561

sqrt = math.sqrt(modulo)
print('%i' %(sqrt))
print('%i' %(sqrt*sqrt))
```

Comment: If it's not a perfect square, you're going to get floating point rounding errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer square root in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390807/integer-square-root-in-python)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of related algorithms that can be used, and the answer in your [linked question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87417/finding-p-and-q-in-rsa-with-a-given-n-p-q10000) shows some of the math behind it. The one I'll show is named [Fermat's factorization method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method).
In python it's relatively easy to implement. I've implemented it myself from the [Basic Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method#Basic_method) writeup in the wikipedia article.

```py
def is_perfect_square(x: int):
    """
    If x is a perfect square then True, sqrt(x) is returned, else False, ceiling(sqrt(x)) is returned
    """
    sqrt = math.isqrt(x)
    return (True, sqrt) if sqrt ** 2 == x else (False, sqrt + 1)


def fermat_factor(n: int):
    is_square, a = is_perfect_square(n)
    b2 = a ** 2 - n
    while True:
        is_square, sqrt = is_perfect_square(b2)
        if is_square:
            break
        b2 += a + a + 1
        a += 1
    return a + sqrt, a - sqrt
```

This method is fast only when there is a factor close to the square root of the number you're trying to factor, and this will be true if n = p*q and p and q are relatively close together as in your problem.

Answer (score -2):

The number you are testing with is not a perfect square. As such this means that the returned value has been rounded to some degree.

This will mean you are getting a rounding error due to the size of the value you are loosing accuracy. I would recommend looking at explicitly declaring your number as a Decimal. This should help.